# Convert existing DateTime to a different format

Tags: powershell

I have a DateTime object from a `Get-ADUser` which is stored into `$logonDt`. This is actually the returned value from an attribute in AD, namely `LastLogonDate`.

A `gettype()` confirms it is of type `DateTime` but it is in an American layout.

How can I take this existing `DateTime` object and re-format as UK, and `dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Get-Date $logondt -f "dd/MM/yyyy" and change the format string as you like.
See https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849887.aspx for the details.

You cannot change the formatting after it is stored in the variable but you could access the single values, like $logondt.day etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
//PowerShell's string formatting (–f) operator:

PS >$date = [DateTime] "05/09/1998 1:23 PM"
PS >"{0:dd-MM-yyyy @ hh:mm:ss}" -f $date
09-05-1998 @ 01:23:00

//CMDLET
PS >Get-Date -Date "05/09/1998 1:23 PM" -Format "dd-MM-yyyy @ hh:mm:ss"
09-05-1998 @ 01:23:00
```

Comment: Yes so you put your dateobject into format      $date = [DateTime] $yourdateobject

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Date -format 'MM/dd/YYY`
The format can be whatever you want and there are characters to represent almost every kinda of date-time unit (month, day, century, etc.)

You can find more info here.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx